# Date format in jsp

Tags: java, string, date, format

I need to convert the date from request parameter to string in dateformat 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

I have tried the following

```
String MyDate = request.getParameter("DayCal");
formatdate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date date = (Date) formatdate.parse(MyDate);
String DisplayDate= formatdate.format(date);
```

But i am getting incorrect results
if the request.getParameter("DayCal") = 01/01/2010; the DisplayDate = 0006/07/03

Please help...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You will need two `SimpleDateFormat`s - one for parsing and one for formatting:

```
String MyDate = request.getParameter("DayCal");
SimpleDataFormat parseDate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDataFormat formatDdate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = (Date) parseDate.parse(MyDate);
String DisplayDate= formatDate.format(date);
```

(I added dashes instead of slashes, because that was your initial requirement).

Answer (score 0):

From your code,  `request.getParameter()` returns date as `dd/MM/YYYY` or `mm/dd/yyyy`, but your `SimpleDateFormat()` is given `yyyy/MM/dd` parameters which doesnot match `MyDate`.
Instead SimpleDateFormat() should be given `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`.