# JSP format date and time

Tags: jsp

I am creating one module in jsp, in which I
have to show auto generated date & time on the page.

Date & Time is generated but it is in
MM/DD/YY - HH/MM/SS i.e. 10/23/2014 - 15:15:22 format . But i want to display it as   23/10/2014  - 03:15 PM

I have to format the time in my JSPcode.

Anybody have any idea/code for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date format in jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011206/date-format-in-jsp)

Comment: @BasilBourque It's not duplicate. `SimpleDateFormat` can't be used in JSP file. I never suggest to use *Scriplet*.

Answer (score 1):

In JSP, you can use [JSTL fmt tag library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) that provides a set of tags for parsing and formatting locale-sensitive numbers and dates.

Read more [Oracle Tutorial - Internationalization Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL6.html) and [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/)

Sample code:

```
<c:set value="10/23/2014 - 15:15:22" var="dateString" />

<fmt:parseDate value="${dateString}" var="dateObject"
                                      pattern="MM/dd/yyyy - HH:mm:ss" />

<fmt:formatDate value="${dateObject}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm a" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use java.text.SimpleDateFormat to format to any pattern you want!

```
Date date = new Date(); 
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy '-' hh:mm a");
System.out.println(dt1.format(date));
```

More info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: OP is looking for formatting date in JSP not in Servlet or Java code. `SimpleDateFormat` can't be used in JSP file and never suggest to use Scriplet.